# What is this symbol in Photoshop CS3

Tags: adobe-photoshop

What does this symbol in Photoshop CS3 mean? It doesn't look like a standard layer symbol, but yet it has gradient styles on it without any layer effects applied.

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

That arrow downwards means it is being clipped. The layer under this one is the clipping mask.

This has the effect that layers deeper down are not affected by this. Only the one directly beneath.

This tecnique is very usefull when using adjustment-, fill- or other effects layers because it limits the effect to just one layer instead of affecting the whole stack.